# Handling this multi-threading scenario in the database?

Tags: mysql, locking

I am working on sample bus ticket booking application,in I am facing these two multi-threading scenarios.

**Scenario 1**
1: Let's say there are two users, they both pick a particular seat and submit form. Now since a seat can be allocated to one user only, I can solve this race condition through select .. for update query along the lines of

```
select * from bus_seats where seat_id = x for update;
update bus_seats set user_id  = y where seat_id = x;
```

For first user it will lock the row and we can allocate the seat to him, and for the second user, the transaction will be blocked and when it gets unblocked, it will know that the seat is already taken , hence there will be no conflicts.

The other scenario which I am not able to resolve is this. Say we don't allow the users to pick their seats but instead pick the first seat randomly that is not taken. Say

```
select top * from bus_seats where user_id is null for update;
```

This should return a non taken seat and we can allocate it to the customer. However, say there are two concurrent users and 10 seats are available. In this scenario, there is a possibility, second user might get blocked because of same row being assigned to him as user1. But, since 10 seats are available, it should not happen.

So can anyone explain to me,how do I handle locking in the second scenario? Is using select..for update correct in this scenario?